# Horizontal view and Submit button in Crispy form Does not work

Tags: python, django, forms

The Vertical Layout in crispy form is working by default but the horizontal layout for the form and Submit button are not appearing .. i think there is some problem with `__init__` but the compiler shows it all right

views.py

```
class sessioncreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):

     model=Sessions
     #fields=['title','abstract','track','speaker']
     form_class=SessionForm

     def form_valid(self, form):
         form.save();
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/sessions')
```

form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from app.models import Sessions
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class SesionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Sessions
        fields=['title','abstract','track','speaker']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

session_form.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: put call of `super()` on the end of the constructor

Comment: i'm using Python 3.x so tried calling super method by ' super().__init__() ' is this the right method  ....if so not can you tell me how to call it with right no.of arguments  :)

Comment: just... take it as it is here, but put it at the end of the constructor.